# How to parse XML / RSS feeds and store them in Database

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss, atom-feed

How to parse XML / RSS feeds and store them in Database. I have set of RSS feeds to parse and store them in my DB tables.

are there any code / tutorials available for this.

Please help.

Comment: these are two problems: How to parse an RSS feed. The other is "How to save data to a DB". Both problems have been answered before on StackOverflow. So use the Search Function please. If you still dont know how to do it after evaluating the existing Q&As, update your question and point out what exactly you are having problems with.s

Answer (score 5):

This seems pretty helpful for the first part.

http://www.bobulous.org.uk/coding/php-xml-feeds.html

It'd then just be a case of a simple connect and insert into a database:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p3.html

Comment: Note that this comment is flagged by some users, and I think it is because it only has links only without inline explanation.

Comment: For future reference, please include relevant sections from the links here.

Comment: Thanks, I do. This was 3 years ago!